# Using multiple logical operators in python

Tags: python, python-2.7

I was a bit curious if there's something that I was missing in the code below,

The logic I want the user to enter either `"Y"` or `"H"` or `"E"`, which I would like to transfer to another class using a `return` statement. I use the `else` part to return boolean `False` if otherwise.

There is a `while` loop that would send the control back to this same function until the user enters the required value.

On running the program it never enters the `else` part no matter what input is received.

```
def getUserIngameOption(self):

    userIngameOption=raw_input("Please Enter Y -> for Turn | H -> Hint | E -> to End")        
    userDesc=userIngameOption.upper()


     if not ( userDesc==("Y") or ("H") or ("E")):

         print "Mate PLEASE JUST TYPE WHATTTT is asked for !! not this",userDesc
         return False
     else:
         self.userOpt=userDesc
         print "This is detail that you got>>>",self.userOpt
         return self.userOpt
```

Comment: The original title for this question is "Using multiple bitwise operator in python."  Just as a comment, this is a **logical** `or`, not a **bitwise** `or`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What is happening is that each one is being evaluated separately, you will need to explicitly compare each value.

```
if not ( userDesc=="Y" or userDesc=="H" or userDesc=="E")
```

"E" and "H" will evaluate to True in your current code.

Answer (score 7):

You arent making the comparison correctly. You are ORing the result of the first comparison with the boolean value of 'H' and 'E'. Since 'H' and 'E' have a boolean value of True, the IF statement will always be False (since you are inverting the condition's result with `not`).

Change this:

```
if not (userDesc==("Y") or ("H") or ("E"))
```

to:

```
if userDesc not in ("Y","H","E"):
```

Answer (score 1):

This the the correct method :

```
if not ( userDesc=="Y" or userDesc=="H" or userDesc=="E")
```

or this :

```
if  userDesc  not in ("H","Y","E").
```

Answer (score 0):

if not ( userDesc==("Y") or ("H") or ("E")) means  (userDesc==("Y")) or (("H")) or (("E")) and the second and third terms are always true.